# C++ double to hex console output need help in resolving

Tags: c++, cout

**my code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double A = 100.35;
    cout.precision(0);
    cout << std::hexfloat << std::fixed << std::left << A << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Current output:**
100

**my expected output:**
x64

**Explanation:**
I want to print the hex value of decimal part of double. But I have been unsuccessful in getting this. need help. Any help in this direction will be appreciated.

Comment: `cout << std::hex << int(A) << endl;` ?

Comment: i have tried the above re-arrangement, it does not solve the issue.

Comment: Don't rearrange. Try them one at a time instead.

Comment: @StoryTeller Does it?  I'm not super familiar with the different flags, but I was looking at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hexfloat/) which says that `hexfloat` is equivalent to `fixed | scientific`

Comment: What about "int i = (int)A; cout << std::hex << i << endl;"

Comment: @Hill [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) specifies that the old values are unset.

Comment: @Robert, in the above question 100 is a sample value, the real problem i am solving has a huge range of numbers. So I am not casting to int.

Comment: @StoryTeller So it's not just bitwise ORing them, it's actually just replacing the value with the most recent one.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Hill That is correct. But regardless, I'm still failing to understand what the OP tries to accomplish. The cast may be the way to go in second thought.

Comment: @StoryTeller for too large doubles, casting to int before hex printing is not an option. There seems to be no way to change std::hexfloat precision (could be solved by floor()) nor to print a fixed hexfloat.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is simply not possible. `std::hex` (the output you're looking for) only works for integral arguments, and `std::hexfloat` uses an undesirable format. You need to cast or round.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double A = 100.35;
    cout.precision(0);
    cout << std::hex << std::showbase << std::lround(A) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```